# Difference between content in uiwebview and mobile safari?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, safari

I am showing a twitter feed in a uiwebview... however there is a problem: it appears significantly differently in the uiwebview then what it does in mobile safari. Ultimately, I much prefer the look of the feed as it is shown in mobile safari. Is there any way to 'trick' the web view into displaying itself as safari? Possibly by altering the user agent? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up altering the user agent. App made it past apple review fine.

Comment: What was the original user agent, and what did you alter it to?

Answer (score -1):

`UIWeView` and Safari doesn't display all the pages as the same..There can be minor differences in formatting in `UIWebView` which won't be found in Safari..

Solution to this is to use `javascript` to alter the WebView itself programmatically to display things right..

more info avaialble in **UIWebView Class Reference** doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)